# Why does GitHub Desktop auto-resolve conflicts?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-merge-conflict, github-desktop

I am not a programmer, but a game artist. I have limited knowledge on Git and Git LFS so this might be a bad question.

When doing a merge, GitHub Desktop will over say it has s=resolved a conflict for me, instead of letting me choose which version to use. This has in fact become such a problem with many programmers I work with, that we do all of our merges in Sourcetree.

Why would GitHub Desktop do this? It's incredibly annoying. Can I disable it?

Comment: Have you already resolved the conflict beforehand?  If so, you're probably using git rerere.

Comment: I have not, and I have never enabled rerere, which I am hearing of for the first time.

Comment: Are you using a custom tool to do this?  Like a special merge driver for Unity files or such?  Is there anything in `.gitattributes` that indicates custom merging or tooling for the files you're seeing this happen with?

Comment: I'm using Git LFS, no other special tools. Using it for Unreal Engine projects in a team. GitAttributes is just a list of file types for LFS, like these:

`*.uasset filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text`

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bABHC.png)

It looks something like that when it resolves for me, with no option to pick the version to use myself.